# ArcGIS JavaScript 4 Layout

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layouts

I am getting started with ArcGIS JavaScript 4. I want to create a layout with header menu, left pane and right pane with map. All the ESRI examples seem to refer to JavaScript 3. In the code below when I try to use this with JavaScript 4 API I get a 404.

Is there a difference in the way layouts are created in JavaScript 4 API?

Is it still with Dojo?

In the head tag I have :

```
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/esri/themes/light/main.css">
 <script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/"></script>
```

then in script tag after head is closed:

```
   <script>
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
  dojo.require("esri.map");
  dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");
  dojo.require("esri.IdentityManager");

require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView"
], function(Map, MapView) {

var map = new Map({
  basemap: "topo-vector"
});

var view = new MapView({
  container: "viewDiv",
  map: map,
  center: [174.80500, -36.82700], // longitude, latitude
  zoom: 11
 });
});
```

This results in This code results in a 404 error for https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/dojo/dijit.layout.BorderContainer.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Answer (score 1):

The answer was not to use dojo but just some css:

```
    <style>
  html, body {
    padding: 30;
    margin: 30;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
  }
   #listDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
  }
  #viewDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
  }
</style>
```

Then in body:

```
  <body>
<div id="listDiv">
  <h1>** TASKS **</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Deployment Task 1</li>
    <li>Deployment Task 2</li>
    <li>Deployment Task 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
```